# COM Object opens in Windows PowerShell, but not PowerShell Core

Tags: .net, powershell, .net-core, office-interop, com-interop

I'm trying to use a OneNote COM Object in Powershell, and after it failing to open (as evidenced by `$onenote | Get-Member` not displaying any methods), I tried the default Windows Powershell as opposed to my daily-driven PowerShell Core. To my surprise, it opened perfectly.

Both had empty `$PROFILE` scripts when I tested. Installed module lists differ slightly, but none of the differences would explain why I'm unable to interface with a COM object on one or the other. Does anyone have any input as to why this could be? I'm absolutely baffled, and can't write a script the way I want to without Powershell Core features unavailable in Windows PowerShell.

Steps to reproduce:

```
Add-Type -Path <path to Visual Studio Tools for Office's distribution of the Microsoft.Office.Interop.OneNote assembly since it isn't installed with Office for some reason>
$OneNote = New-Object -ComObject OneNote.Application
$OneNote | Get-Member
```

Running this code with Office 2016 in Windows PowerShell results in a perfect COM object. Running it in PowerShell Core does start the OneNote process, but adds none of the interface members to `$OneNote` and attempting to call them results in a COM Object Marshal error as it cannot find the method called.

Does anyone have any insight? Thanks!

Comment: FWIW, I can reproduce (the first line isn't even needed in my Windows Powershell, it works w/o it). Spying with procmon (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/procmon), the two are using very different registry calls. It may be due to .NET core vs .NET Framework used internally which broke many COM support features ... You should ask in PowerShell Core repo https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues

Comment: @SimonMourier Appreciated. I wanted to triple check that this isn’t just an issue with my system that I can fix before opening an issue. Thanks for letting me know it’s reproducible!